# SQL Query to parse survey results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

First off, I have attempted to search for an answer, but honestly don't know exactly what to search for...

I have a dataset I've imported into SQL Server and need to get usable data from it. Here's the format...

```
Teacher     Period    Question1    Question2    Question3
Jane Doe    1         Agree        Agree        Strongly Agree
Jane Doe    2         Disagree     Agree        Agree
John Doe    2         Agree        Disagree     Agree
John Doe    4         Disagree     Agree        Strongly Disagree
Jane Doe    3         Agree        Agree        Agree
```

and so on...
What I need is to be able to return a count of Jane Doe's different answers for Question1, Question2, etc. I need to return for Jane's Question1, there are 2 Agrees and 1 Disagree. I need this for multiple teachers.

I have tried using GROUP BY but I must not be doing something right. 
I've tried variations of:

```
SELECT Teacher, COUNT(Q1) AS Q1Result, COUNT(Q2) AS Q2Result
FROM Survey
GROUP BY Teacher, Q1, Q2
```

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

So, this is the query that ended up getting me what I needed. My data needed to be unpivoted I believe to make this much easier. This is the query that got me what I was looking for...

```
SELECT s.Teacher,
       q.Question,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'Strongly Agree' THEN 1 END) StronglyAgreeCount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'Agree' THEN 1 END) AgreeCount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'Neutral' THEN 1 END) NeutralCount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'Disagree' THEN 1 END) DisagreeCount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'Strongly Disagree' THEN 1 END)     StronglyDisagreeCount
FROM   PCSSSurvey s 
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES(s.Q1, 'Question01'),(s.Q2, 'Question02'),(s.Q3, 'Question03'),(s.Q4, 'Question04'),(s.Q5, 'Question05'),(s.Q6, 'Question06'),(s.Q7, 'Question07'),(s.Q8, 'Question08'),(s.Q9, 'Question09'),(s.Q10, 'Question10'),(s.Q11, 'Question11'),(s.Q12, 'Question12'),(s.Q13, 'Question13')) q(val,question)
GROUP BY s.Teacher, q.Question
ORDER BY s.Teacher, q.Question
```

Comment: please show the expected output and tag the database you are using.

Comment: Did you abbreviate the column names for `Question1` and `Question2` in your SQL?  You have it counting `Q1` and `Q2` which don't exist in this context.

Comment: Would you group "strongly agree" with "agree"?

Comment: SELECT Teacher, Q1, COUNT(Q1) AS Q1Result, Q2, COUNT(Q2) AS Q2Result
FROM Survey
GROUP BY Teacher, Q1, Q2 

Show result of this sql.

Comment: Sorry Timothy, yes, I did abbreviate the column names as Q1, Q2, etc.

Comment: SqlZim, no, strongly agree, agree, disagree all should be counted separately. There are 5 choices ranging from strongly disagree to strongly agree.

Comment: I can't get the results I get returned to show up correctly. It returns Q1 and Q2 matching for each result.

Comment: what version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: @SqlZim I'm using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this to get counts for all options per question.

```
SELECT s.Teacher,
       q.Question,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'Agree' THEN 1 END) AgreeCount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'Strongly Agree' THEN 1 END) StronglyAgreeCount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'Disagree' THEN 1 END) DisagreeCount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN val = 'Strongly Disagree' THEN 1 END) StronglyDisagreeCount
FROM   Survey s 
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES(s.Question1, 'Question1'),(s.Question2, 'Question2'),(s.Question3, 'Question3')) q(val,question)
GROUP BY s.Teacher, q.Question
ORDER BY s.Teacher, q.Question

ouput:
Teacher  Question  AgreeCount  StronglyAgreeCount DisagreeCount StronglyDisagreeCount
-------- --------- ----------- ------------------ ------------- ---------------------
Jane Doe Question1 2           0                  1             0
Jane Doe Question2 3           0                  0             0
Jane Doe Question3 2           1                  0             0
John Doe Question1 1           0                  1             0
John Doe Question2 1           0                  1             0
John Doe Question3 1           0                  0             1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not normalized (each question response should be its own row, not a column). You'll need to unpivot the data somehow if you want to do true relational queries on the data.

We could use an explicit `UNPIVOT` but I think using a `UNION` makes it clear what's going on:

```
SELECT
    Teacher, Period, 'Q1' AS Question, Question1 AS Response
FROM
    Survey

UNION ALL

SELECT
    Teacher, Period, 'Q2' AS Question, Question2 AS Response
FROM
    Survey

UNION ALL

SELECT
    Teacher, Period, 'Q3' AS Question, Question3 AS Response
FROM
    Survey
```

- I use a `UNION ALL` to improve performance as we don't need a true set-union result (i.e. duplicate removal).
- Repeat the `SELECT` for each additional question column.

This will transform your data into something like this:

```
Teacher     Period    Question    Response
Jane Doe    1         Q1          Agree
Jane Doe    1         Q2          Agree
Jane Doe    1         Q3          Strongly Agree
Jane Doe    2         Q1          Disagree
Jane Doe    2         Q2          Agree
Jane Doe    2         Q3          Agree
... -- and so on
```

Then you can run relational queries on this data:

> What I need is to be able to return a count of Jane Doe's different answers for Question 1

This is done like so:

```
SELECT
    Teacher,
    COUNT( DISTINCT Response ) AS DifferentAnswerCount
FROM
    /* inner query */
WHERE
    Question = 'Q1'
GROUP BY
    Teacher
```

Or to get it for all questions:

```
SELECT
    Teacher,
    Question,
    COUNT( DISTINCT Response ) AS DifferentAnswerCount
FROM
    /* inner query */
GROUP BY
    Teacher,
    Question
```

The full query:

```
SELECT
    Teacher,
    Question,
    COUNT( DISTINCT Response ) AS DifferentAnswerCount
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Teacher, Period, 'Q1' AS Question, Question1 AS Response
        FROM
            Survey

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            Teacher, Period, 'Q2' AS Question, Question2 AS Response
        FROM
            Survey

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            Teacher, Period, 'Q3' AS Question, Question3 AS Response
        FROM
            Survey
    )
WHERE
    Question = 'Q1'
GROUP BY
    Teacher,
    Question
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are going for in the final output but this methodology should give you a clear path to follow and an easily understandable output.

```
SELECT 
    Teacher 
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Q1 IN ('Agree','Strongly Agree') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Q1-Agree'
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Q1 IN ('Disagree','Strongly Disagree') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Q1-Disagree'
    ...
FROM
    input
GROUP BY 
    Teacher
```

By doing this you will create a unique record for each teacher and then can defined groups for each output. 
If you just want to know how many times they answered the question, you can use counts, if you want to count conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`apply()`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to unpivot your table first instead of chaining `union all`.

test setup: http://rextester.com/VGESS44812

```
create table t (
    Teacher varchar(32)
  , Period int
  , Question1 varchar(32)
  , Question2 varchar(32)
  , Question3 varchar(32)
  );
insert into t  (Teacher,Period,Question1,Question2,Question3) values
 ('Jane Doe',1,'Agree','Agree','Strongly Agree')
,('Jane Doe',2,'Disagree','Agree','Agree')
,('John Doe',2,'Agree','Disagree','Agree')
,('John Doe',4,'Disagree','Agree','Strongly Disagree')
,('Jane Doe',3,'Agree','Agree','Agree')
,('Zim',0,'<3','apply()',null);
```

query:

```
select 
    Teacher
  , Question
  , Answer
  , AnswerCount=count(*)
  from t
    outer apply (
      values (1,Question1),(2,Question2),(3,Question3)
    ) as x (Question,Answer)
  group by Teacher, Question, Answer
```

output:

```
+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------+
| Teacher  | Question |      Answer       | AnswerCount |
+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------+
| Jane Doe |        1 | Agree             |           2 |
| Jane Doe |        1 | Disagree          |           1 |
| Jane Doe |        2 | Agree             |           3 |
| Jane Doe |        3 | Agree             |           2 |
| Jane Doe |        3 | Strongly Agree    |           1 |
| John Doe |        1 | Agree             |           1 |
| John Doe |        1 | Disagree          |           1 |
| John Doe |        2 | Agree             |           1 |
| John Doe |        2 | Disagree          |           1 |
| John Doe |        3 | Agree             |           1 |
| John Doe |        3 | Strongly Disagree |           1 |
| Zim      |        1 | <3                |           1 |
| Zim      |        2 | apply()           |           1 |
| Zim      |        3 | NULL              |           1 |
+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: You are all smarter than I'll ever be at SQL queries. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems  that a single query as suggested in some of the comments will not get you what you want. My suggestion would be to go for three separate queries like

```
select Teacher, Question1, count(*) cnt from tblx group by Teacher, Question1;
select Teacher, Question2, count(*) cnt from tblx group by Teacher, Question2;
select Teacher, Question3, count(*) cnt from tblx group by Teacher, Question3
```

See here for a working example: http://rextester.com/CTA10481